# Build Successful but not running on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, gpu

I download the code of Brad Larson from  [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). When I run it. It shows the build successful but it's not run in simulator. please direct me in right direction.

I check the method in app delegate file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
.......
```

}

not called.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scheme you're trying to run is probably not set correctly (it wasn't for me when i downloaded the code either). Just change the scheme to the one you want to run and try again (the top left area of XCode has a drop down box which is probably set to "GPUImage" or something similar, change it to "CubeExample" or whatever and it should work). However don't expect much from running in the simulator, [according to the issues page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/214) you mostly need to run on the device.

Comment: +1 for you..thanks for quick reply.. you are right. now the simulator loads. i have to run this on device. thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why this happens to some people and not others. Switching schemes always seems to fix it from then on out.

Comment: @BradLarson is it not just a saved XCode project file pointing at the wrong scheme?

Comment: @BradLarson Hello Sir, you are my favorite and happy to see your comment in my question :) there is any way to check the output in my Simulator? many thanks

Comment: @Stack.Blue - I added compile-time checks in the latest repository code to fix some bugs with the Simulator, but you won't be able to simulate anything dealing with the camera there. Processing still images and movies should work, though.

Comment: i could not find any option to change the scheme. i could see the drop down box which is in left side of xcode. In that drop down there is 5 options 1.GPUImage 2.Documentation 3.Edit Scheme 4.New Scheme 5.manage Scheme. In these 5 where i have to change the scheme. please guide me